# How to bold "names.arg" in barplot()

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I would like to bold the names argument (e.g. `names.arg`) in `barplot()` in R. For example:

```
bars <- as.table(c(1,2))
barplot(bars, names.arg = c("MMM", "NNN"), cex.names = 2)
```

Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
barplot(bars, names.arg = c("MMM", "NNN"), cex.names = 2, font = 2)
```

but as you commented, this will bold axis as well. Now let's do the following:

```
barplot(bars, names.arg = c("MMM", "NNN"), cex.names = 2, font = 2, yaxt = "n")  ## suppress plotting axis
axis(side = 2)  ## add axis on the left later
```

That is, we suppress plotting axis when setting `font = 2`, but adding axis later.

[image: bold]

The following is quoted from `?par`:

> font
>
> An integer which specifies which font to use for text. If possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to plain text (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4 to bold italic. Also, font 5 is expected to be the symbol font, in Adobe symbol encoding. On some devices font families can be selected by family to choose different sets of 5 fonts.